# Meaning of "satisfiable" network path

Tags: c, networking, darwin

In Apple's Network framework, one of the [`nw_path_status_t`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nw_path_status_t?language=objc) enum values is `nw_path_status_satisfiable`:

> The path is not currently available, but establishing a new connection may activate the path.

What exactly does this mean?  At first, I thought it represented the case where Wi-Fi is enabled but not connected to any network.  However, after disconnecting from my Wi-Fi network (but leaving Wi-Fi enabled) and running my program, the status was revealed to be `nw_path_status_unsatisfied`.